# How do I print a random number into a tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a program, using widgets, that allows you to press the button "roll" and shows the corresponding number. Right now, I am having trouble with printing a number in the label (instead of terminal which is all I know how to do).

Here is some of my code:

```
def test():

    # Button that when clicked, will print out random number on screen
    import tkinter as tk
    from random import randrange

    constant = tk.Tk()

    def main():

        screen()
        frame = frame_dice()
        dice_button(frame)
        tk.mainloop()

    def screen():

        canvas = tk.Canvas(constant, width = 1800, height = 1250)
        canvas.pack()
        return canvas

    def random_num():

        num = randrange(1, 7)
        return num

    def clicked():

        num = random_num()
        return num

    def frame_dice():

        frame = tk.Frame(constant, bg = "yellow")
        frame.place(relheight = .2, relwidth = .2, relx = .4, rely = .5)
        return frame

    def dice_button(frame):

        button = tk.Button(frame, text = "Roll", bg = "red", command = clicked)
        button.place(relx = .1, rely = .1, relheight = .6, relwidth = .7)

    main()

test()
```

If you need any further clarification on the question, comment below and I would be honored to answer.

Comment: Have you read any documentation or done any research? There are countless examples on this site for how to update a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have to, within the `clicked` method, change the properties of whatever object you want to display the dice roll on.

I'm not sure what *label* you were referring to in your question, since there are no label objects in your code, but the program below shows how to modify the button itself to show the last roll:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randrange
constant = tk.Tk()

def main():
    screen()
    frame = frame_dice()
    dice_button(frame)
    tk.mainloop()

def screen():
    canvas = tk.Canvas(constant, width = 300, height = 150)
    canvas.pack()
    return canvas

def clicked():
    num = randrange(1, 7)
    button["text"] = f"Roll (last roll was {num})"

def frame_dice():
    frame = tk.Frame(constant, bg = "yellow")
    frame.place(relheight = .8, relwidth = .8, relx = .1, rely = .1)
    return frame

def dice_button(frame):
    global button
    button = tk.Button(frame, text = "Roll", bg = "red", command = clicked)
    button.place(relx = .1, rely = .1, relheight = .8, relwidth = .8)

main()
```

I've made `button` global so it can be properly changed in multiple methods<sup>(a)</sup> but the important bit is this:

```
def clicked():
    num = randrange(1, 7)
    button["text"] = f"Roll (last roll was {num})"
```

It's that last line that changes the button text property to show how it can be done:

> [image]

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Normally, if you rebind a variable anywhere in a method, it's local to that method - using `global` overrides that.